# Two tcp clients, one for reading, the other for writing

Tags: python, python-asyncio

You need to write code for the tcp server.
The first client that connects will **only send** some data to the server, so the server should **only read** that data.
The second client should **only read** the data, therefore the server should **only send** some data to this client. In my case, the server should send data to the second client every 3 seconds.

How can I use two tcp connections at the same time. One to receive data and the other to send it?

It is necessary to use asynchrony in the python language.

I tried, here is my code.

> server.py

```py
import asyncio
import time

import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s:%(message)s',
    datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
)

client_loop = True
first_client_addr = None
msg = 'test'

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    global client_loop
    global first_client_addr
    global msg

    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    logging.info(f'New client {addr}')
    
    if first_client_addr == None:
        first_client_addr = addr

    if addr == first_client_addr:
        request = None
        while client_loop:
            request = (await reader.read(1024)).decode('utf8')
            msg = request
            logging.info(f'Received {request!r} from {addr!r}')

    else:
        while client_loop:
            response = msg
            writer.write(response.encode('utf8'))
            await writer.drain()
            logging.info(f'Sended {response!r} to {addr!r}')
            time.sleep(3)
    writer.close()


async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '0.0.0.0', 8686)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(run_server())
```

The first step is to connect the client to send user data.
[image: first client]

Then, as soon as the second client connects, I stop receiving any data from the first client, that is, they simply cannot be read.
[image: second client]

As soon as I kill the second client, the server starts reading data from the first client again. Server log:

```
08-04-2022 17:19:23,INFO:New client ('127.0.0.1', 47314)
08-04-2022 17:19:23,INFO:Received 'First connection message, client 2.' from ('127.0.0.1', 47314)
08-04-2022 17:19:25,INFO:Received 'g' from ('127.0.0.1', 47314)
08-04-2022 17:19:26,INFO:Received 'a' from ('127.0.0.1', 47314)
08-04-2022 17:19:27,INFO:New client ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:27,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:30,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:33,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:36,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:39,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:42,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:45,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
08-04-2022 17:19:48,INFO:Sended 'a' to ('127.0.0.1', 47316)
```

How can this happen, because these are two different clients that should not influence each other.
Please help me solve this problem. Explain why this is happening or write code.

Here is the code of two of my clients, but it is not really needed.

> client_send.py

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def send_client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8686
    )

    message = 'First connection message, client 2.'
    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    print('First connection for client 2 done.')

    print('Start loop')
    data = None
    while data != 'quit':
        data = input()
        writer.write(data.encode())
        await writer.drain()

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(send_client())
```

> client_listen.py

```py
import asyncio

async def listen_client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8686
    )

    message = 'First connection message, client 1.'
    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    print('First connection for client 1 done.')

    print('Loop has been started')
    data = None
    while data != 'quit':
        response = await reader.read(1024)
        data = response.decode()
        print(f'Received: {data!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(listen_client())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this `sleep(3)`. This put to sleep the whole server so it isn't receiving/sending anything. In asyncio code you need to use `await asyncio.sleep(3)`.

I also slightly restructured the server code:

```py
import asyncio
import logging


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
    datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",
)

msg = "test"
clients = []


async def handle_read(reader, addr):
    global msg

    while True:
        msg = (await reader.read(1024)).decode("utf-8")
        logging.info(f"Received {msg!r} from {addr!r}")


async def handle_write(writer, addr):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

        writer.write(msg.encode("utf8"))
        await writer.drain()
        logging.info(f"Sended {msg!r} to {addr!r}")


async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    global num_clients

    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")
    logging.info(f"New client {addr}")

    if not clients:
        # first client is modifying `msg`
        clients.append(asyncio.create_task(handle_read(reader, addr)))
    else:
        # all other clients are receiving `msg` every 3 seconds
        clients.append(asyncio.create_task(handle_write(writer, addr)))

    await clients[-1]


async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, "0.0.0.0", 8686)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(run_server())
```

---

The first client is *special* - is modifying the `msg`. All other clients are receiving every 3 seconds the `msg` the first client sent.